# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory [Python]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIOmd.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVxe2.png)
I'm writing a discord bot and I got an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
The full path to the file is already specified, but the error still occurs.

I already specified the full path, but I got an error Error "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape. I assigned r but this error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is raw strings don't escape single `\` since the program thinks you want to escape the next character. For example, `\'` escapes the `'` string. Therefore, to make your code function simply replace single `\` with double `\\` and you can remove the raw string.
Example:

```
location = r'C:\Users\ABC' # is invalid
location = 'C:\\Users\\ABC' # is valid
```

*Recommendation: Please don't add image links next time, and provide code as snippets rather than a hyperlink.*